# Image interpolation in Matlab with J. Wu's fast linear interpolation method

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate images with the fast linear interpolation method from Jeffrey Wu [1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28376-faster-linear-interpolation) but it fails. The Matlab standard method is

```
    [h_i, w_i, d_i] = size(img);
    [xi, yi] = meshgrid(linspace(0, w_i-1, w_i), linspace(0, h_i-1, h_i));
    p2p = zeros(size(yo,1), size(xo,2), 3, 'uint8');
    for k = 1:d_i; p2p(:,:,k) = interp2(xi, yi, img(:,:,k), xo, yo); end
```

but when switching to `(Wu: function v = lininterp2(X, Y, V, x, y))`

```
for k = 1:d_i; p2p(:,:,k) = lininterp2(xi, yi, img(:,:,k), xo, yo); end
```

I got the error `[length(X), length(Y)] does not match size(V)` caused by

```
if ((length(X) ~= size(V, 1)) || (length(Y) ~= size(V, 2))),
error('[length(X), length(Y)] does not match size(V)'); end
```

The sizes are equal `hX = hY = hV; wX = wY = wV; dX = dY = dV;` but because `X,Y (xi,yi)` are meshgrids their length (not h or w) is certainly larger than the h or w of the corresponding image channel V. Any idea how this image interpolation might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the description at the link you provided, I can see these two points:

> 4. Order of X/Y arguments switched for 2d and 3d interpolate
> 5. Only takes a scalar query value (I will change this sometime perhaps, when I feel like it, or if I see that people actually care
>    and want to use my function)

After looking at the code, my understanding of point (4) is that the input image should be transposed.

My understanding of point (5) is that the query values `xo` and `yo` must be scalars (so you must iterate over the image in a loop).

More importantly, the lazy and informal nature of this "documentation" suggests to me that you should think very carefully before trusting this code.

I find it almost impossible to believe that this could be faster than `interp2` when processing a whole image. It literally calculates a single pixel value by bilinear interpolation:

```matlab
v = V(pindexx, pindexy) * (1 - slopex) * (1 - slopey) + V( indexx, pindexy) * slopex * (1 - slopey) ... 
  + V(pindexx,  indexy) * (1 - slopex) *       slopey + V( indexx,  indexy) * slopex *       slopey ;
```

Therefore, I could imagine this being faster for calculating a single pixel value (or perhaps a small handful), but I can't see any attempt at performance optimization whatsoever. Therefore, if your image dimensions are more than a few pixels, then I wouldn't even consider using `lininterp2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight and I will not follow this up. I was lured into this because of the promise of much faster interpolation and the very good feedbacks on the fileexchange page but no word that it is not usable for image interpolation.